# Sum of geometrical series, why can we susbstract?

Tags: sequences-and-series

In the common desmostration of the formula of the sum of the geometrical serie mathematicians multiply the sum (Sm) by r and get r(Sm).

I understand we can do such thing because if we have the equality:

a = b then ax = bx.

The next step is subtract Sm by r(Sm) and this eliminate all the terms except the first of Sm and the last of r(Sm).

What is the principle of this step? Under which law can we perform this subtraction and to expect that the subsequent simplification give us the formula of the sum of the serie.

Comment: Another question, why we do Sm - r(Sm) and not r(Sm) - Sm.

Comment: Do you mean just $(1-r)(1+r+\dots+r^n)=1-r^{n+1}$? This follows simply from algebra - nothing to do with convergence and even holds for any $r$. The usual proof just involves writing
$$
S_n=\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}
$$
and taking the limit.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the mathematical formulas in your MSE questions.  As for the mathematics, do you have any problems with $1 + 2 + 4 + 8 - 2\times(1 + 2 + 4 + 8) = 1 - 16$?

Comment: For the other question, you may do $rS_m - S_m = r^{m+1} - 1$, and get $S_m = \dfrac{r^{m+1}-1}{r-1} = \dfrac{1-r^{m+1}}{1-r}$. Depending on whether $r>1$ or $r<1$, one may find handling positive numbers more convenient, but they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Because, if $\require{cancel}S_m=1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^{m-1}+r^m$, then\begin{align}S_m-rS_m&=1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^{m-1}+r^m-r(1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^{m-1}+r^m)\\&=1+\cancel{r+r^2+\cdots+r^{m-1}+r^m}-\left(\cancel{r+r^2+r^3+\cdots+r^m}+r^{m+1}\right)\\&=1-r^{m+1}.\end{align}